# jQuery remove li's dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i got a ul list like this:

```
  <ul><li>Test</li><li>Test</li></ul>
```

Now im appending from an array like this:

```
    var array = new Array("Element1", "Element2"); 
    var length = array.length;
```

I can only have 2 lines in my UL list (This is much more because i get information from a database)

So now the array has a length of two, then i use `for` to get the result but now i need it do delete the first rows, so if i add 12 li's i need it do delete the 12 first li's from the list, or if i add 2 li's i need it do delete the 2 first li's.

Anyone got a clue? Im kinda stuck right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get a range of the elements matching a selector.

```
$("li").slice(0, -2).remove();
```

Using a negative number as the end of the range counts from the end of the collection.